# clearTimeout doesn't work with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a slider and using a setTimeout function to automatically change class name every 5 sec.

I want to reset the timer again every time i click on the slide selector but it doesn't matter what I do the clearTimeout just doesn't stop the function from firing again..pseudo code below

```
   function autoAddClass(){
       console.log('changing class');
       setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000); 
    }

    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000); // to run the function on load


    $('.post-nav-btn').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      clearTimeout(autoAddClass);
    });
```

Comment: You're not using clearTimeout correctly. Read about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Answer (score 2):

```
var someVar = setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);

//clear the timeout, you don't clear the function
clearTimeout(someVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the setTimeOut in proper manner.
In your code you are clearing the function.

Refer this Link know how to use it. [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

I think this is solution which you wanted.

```
var timeout = null;
function autoAddClass(){
       console.log('changing class');

}
timeout = setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);  // to run the function on load

 $('.post-nav-btn').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```